# How to restrict download in sharepoint search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am using sharepoint OOTB Search and Search results webpart for searching the document from the particular document library which stores only the PDF documents.
        If i click the search results the pdf is opening in the browser itself and there is an option to download and print.
       My requirement is that the user should only view the pdf and there is no option to download and print the document.
      Is there any option to achieve that in all browser support.Any help is appreciated .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point doing it. Even if you can disable download button from page.

As long as user can see and read your pdf, they can just right click and save the PDF on their own.

Unless you can change the user's permission to minimum viewing access. which should disable it.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve only the user can view the document and shouldn't able to download it?

Comment: @Parthasarathy sorry i updated late, you could reduce users permission on this content to only view it. which should help you block download access.

Comment: Hi @NaaHCat I given the view only permission to the user.it still downloadable, I am using OOTB Search results webpart to view the search results, and if i click the search result it opens the pdf in the same window which is downloadable.any way to restrict that.